# XML Attributes to arrays (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xpath

I have an XML which includes many thousands of nodes with information about them in attributes.
Each node is like :

```
<Class Option1="fiahfs;if" Option2="fiowfr0r0" ClassID="1">
<Class Option1="ro;ewaj;frwajro" Option2="afj;wh;fha" Option3="34014upkla" ClassID="2">
....
```

I need to parse that info into PHP arrays with array names being attribute names and the number of element in array equal to ClassID Attribute.
The problem is that some nodes have attributes that other nodes I dont have. I previously used ->attributes() for one selected element as

`$a => $b,
$$a=array();`

then

```
${$a}[(integer)$products['ClassID']]=$b
```

Where $products is simplexml element got from parsing XML with xpath. That basically gave me what i needed - i had a few arrays and i could address my requests like $Option1[1] , $Option2[1], Option1[2]...etc.

But the problem is that if I create that structure using only attribute list of one selected element -there`ll be elements that that one element do not have,but other have, and after a create arrays and then parse XML -there'll not be some arrays. Like if i create arrays from [0] of that example, that will give me $Option1, $Option2, but no $Option3.

When I rebuilt my code to :

```
foreach ($XML->xpath('/idspace/Class') as $products){
foreach($products->attributes() as $a => $b){
if(!isset($$a) $$a=array();
${$a}[(integer)$products['ClassID']]=$b;
}}
```

And after that I tried to foreach($ClassID) - I`ve got only one element in that array.
How can I parse every XML attribute to array while using attribute "ClassID" as element number in array?

Comment: `$XmlElement->children();`

Comment: `${$a}[(integer)$products['ClassID']][] = $b`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite confused with your arrays. For me it sounds strange to have an extra array for each attribute. Why not make one array that contains each element and have the attributes as children. So that in the end you get an array like this:

```
$products = array(
   [1] => array(
       [Option1] => "fiahfs;if",
       [Option2] => "fiowfr0r0",
   ),
   [2] => array(
       [Option1] => "ro;ewaj;frwajro",
       [Option2] => "afj;wh;fha",
       [Option3] => "34014upkla",
   ),
```

In this way you can easily access all the attributes for a given ChildId:
$products[$childId]['Option1'] - or better check if the Attribute-Name exists.

You can use simplexml->attributes()

```
$products = array();  // products will have the result!
foreach ($xml->products as $productXml) {   // don't know your xml structure here, 
                                            // but you need to iterate over every product in the xml
    $singleProduct = array();
    $classId = 0;
    foreach($productXml->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        if ($a == 'ClassID') {
            $classId = $b;
        } else {
            $singleProduct[$a] = $b;
        }
    }
    $products[$classId] = $singleProduct;
}
```

Comment: Yeah,i know that its kind of strange structure. I just do not want to change thousands of strings with that adresses through the whole existing project.Anyway,thanks. Probably ill use that method and change adresses manually.

Comment: If you need the structure, than you have to iterate over all products once -> to figure out all existing attributes. Then create the arrays. Then iterate over all products again and fill ALL of the attribute arrays with data for EACH product (ClassID). You need to figure out, what you can take as a null value for a not existing attribute value for that product.